# Testing rails application with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I would like to test specific folders in the rails application with rake. 
I have made a `parallel.rake` file in `lib/tasks` which contains:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
namespace :test do
    Rails::TestTask.new(fixtures: 'test:prepare') do |t|
        t.pattern = 'test/fixtures/*_test.rb'
    end
end
```

However, it keeps giving me an error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::TestTask
```

I have added `require 'rake/testtask'` to both the `parallel.rake` file and also the `Rakefile`.

All I want to do is run each folder in my tests folder separately. It contains these folders:
`controllers`
`fixtures`
`integration`
`mailers`
`models`

I know I can run controllers and integration folders by running the command `rake test:integration` and `rake test:controllers`.

But how do I test for the other folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it I was using `Rails::TestTask` instead of `Rake::TestTask`

Just change the task file so it becomes:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
  namespace :test do
    Rake::TestTask.new(fixtures: 'test:prepare') do |t|
      t.pattern = 'test/fixtures/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```